# How to get details about the DTS Step in a running job?

Tags: sql, dts

I have scheduled a DTS to run from a scheduled job. The DTS has several steps in it. Now whenever the job is running and I take a look at the jobs section in Enterprise manager, then it always displays the following in the status: Executing Job Step 1'.... although its running all steps properly. How do I know at what step the DTS is running at?

Can I get the status maybe from sql analyzer?

Answer (score 1):

You can add something which can show you where the dts currently running at. `I prefer` best way is to put `alert` using a script. There is no other direct way using which you can trace DTS task !

Answer (score 0):

The display you get is a snap shot. you need to keep refreshing it.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one step in the job, the command to run the DTS package.

If you want to see progress of steps within the package, you need to add something to the DTS package to record each step as it finishes in a logging table.

Comment: Oh. That explains it. Adding an additional step into the DTS to record the current status, would require a lot of work. We have several 100 DTS packages. Is there a way to automate that?

Answer (score 0):

Since the DTS mostly executes against database tables, on the SQLServer side you can find what all sessions are currently active, the statement it is executing etc if you have administrative privileges.  **You can find this under Management as Activity monitor**.